# matching filename base

Tags: javascript, regex

Still learning regex here but I need a little help.

I have this string 
`assets/BigBlueSomething_tn.jpg`

I need to match this
`BigBlueSomething`

Closest I got is this
`` `[^\/][a-zA-Z]+_ ``

Problem is that I keep matching the underscore
I've tried this `[^\/][a-zA-Z]+[^_]` at the advice from several other threads but to no avail.

I'm writing in javascript, I believe there are some regex things that dont work in that language.

Comment: What precisely is the criteria to find the part you want? Everyting between the `/` and `_`? Look at the description of "lookaround operators" at [www.regular-rexpressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you need:

```
var str = 'assets/BigBlueSomething_tn.jpg';
var match = str.split('/')[1].match(/[a-z]+/i)[0];
```

Edit: I used `split` because otherwise you'd have to loop the matches to extract what you need. `match` doesn't capture groups.

```
'assets/BigBlueSomething_tn.jpg'
       -^---------------------^- // .split('/')[1]
       -^--------------^- // .match(/[a-z]+/i)[0]

[a-z] // match any character from a to z
+ // at least one time
/i // case-insensitive to match A-Z as well
```

Comment: I added some explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var text = "assets/BigBlueSomething_tn.jpg";
var matches = /assets\/(.+?)_tn.jpg/gi.exec(text);
if(matches && matches[1]) {
    var str = matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(?:.*\/)?([0-9a-z]+)(?:_[a-z]+)?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i
```

This regex matches "BigBlueSomething" in the following strings:

```
'assets/BigBlueSomething_tn.jpg' 
'BigBlueSomething_tn.jpg'
'BigBlueSomething_TN.jPeG'
'dir1/dir2/BigBlueSomething_tn.gif'
'BigBlueSomething.png'
'BigBlueSomething_thumb.png'
'directory/BigBlueSomething_thumb.JPEG'
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vovkss/gBmdG/).